# C++ techniques for reducing CPU instruction sizes?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, gcc, optimization

Each CPU instruction consumes a number of bytes. The smaller the size, the most instructions which can be held in the CPU cache.

**What techniques are available when writing C++ code which allow you to reduce CPU instruction sizes?**

One example could be reducing the number of FAR jumps (literally, jumps to code across larger addresses). Because the offset is a smaller number, the type used is smaller and the overall instruction is smaller.

I thought GCC's __builtin_expect may reduce jump instruction sizes by putting unlikely instructions further away.

I think I have seen somewhere that its better to use an int32_t rather than int16_t due to being the native CPU integer size and therefore more efficient CPU instructions.

Or is something which can only be done whilst writing assembly?

Comment: What makes you think this is something you need to do?

Comment: -mthumb is a candidate

Comment: Just write good proper code and let the optimizer take care of things like that.

Comment: What makes you believe this is something you can do anything about?

Comment: What makes you think that you are better that the optimizer? Just write good readable and maintainable

Comment: Did you already try `-Os` and see how much it helps?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because you can never help the compiler too much.....

Comment: @user997112 actually you can, in most cases your "optimizations" actually cause slower code, because you don't understand the CPU as much as the compiler does. Also shorter instructions may not be faster, they may just exist for legacy reasons and be implemented in microcode. If that's the case they could be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: I have enough problem with my bugs without worrying about such things.

Comment: @MGetz, good point about the legacy aspect. However I don't agree with this "just let the compiler do it"/"premature optimization is the route of all evil" mentality many on here seem to hold. One of the easiest ways to make code faster is to optimize the memory data layout from the BEGINNING. Writing all the code, THEN profiling afterwards and making optimizations is WAY too late in the process.

Comment: In case people are wondering why on earth would he care about this, I work in an industry where shaving-off CPU cycles is advantageous.

Comment: @user997112 then profile, and then use better algorithms. The fastest cpu cycle is the one never spent

Comment: @user997112: _"you can never help the compiler too much....."_ Right, because after a certain point you stop helping and start hindering.

Comment: @user997112: That logic applies to the high-level design of the program, and writing code with a general eye for efficiency. Specific micro-optimisations, like trying to force a particular machine code layout, can only be done through measurement once you have a working implementation - once measurement has determined that a particular piece of code is actually a bottleneck. On a modern CPU, there's far more to program execution than simply fetching and executing instructions, and trying to optimise that might well undermine other aspects of performance.

Comment: There's always this struggle between "micro" optimization and "macro" optimization. In my experience, people get worried when you jump right to micro optimization because **usually** you can save far more by optimizing algorithms than messing with lower level stuff. We don't actually know that you haven't already optimized "everything" at the macro level, that's just often not the case. At my previous job we had a bunch of engineers pulling hacky nonsense to get rid of a few conditional jump instructions. Meanwhile, every sort was done with either selection or bubble algorithms.

Comment: @iwolf - all the micro-optimizers should post their overall designs, (so we can see how wonderful they are... or not;).

Comment: By The Way, instruction sizes depends on the processor.  The ARM7 processor instructions are either 16-bit (thumb mode) or 32-bit (ARM mode).  So shortening the instruction sizes doesn't apply.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: That can be true for the instructions themselves, but different types of instructions can expect different sizes and counts of operands which also have to be stored in the instruction cache. The example from the question is about the operand size difference between a short-jump and long-jump. Of course, that only applies on hardware with support for both.

Comment: I do this sort of thing regularly, albeit while optimizing for size (squeezing programs into a limited ROM space) rather than indirectly for speed. Most of these savings come from normal re-working the algorithms to simplify programs and shed code. Beyond that what I mostly do is write assembly in C - that is effectively writing assembly code in my head while coaxing the compiler into generating the desired instructions for me. Of course the first step, as always, is simply to _read_ the generated code.

Comment: I would also suggest a full read of [The Intel Optimizations Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) which quickly shows that instruction length... is a problem only *sometimes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we've all fought over micro/macro optimization, let's try to help with the actual question.

I don't have a full, definitive answer, but you might be able to start [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Costs.html). GCC has some macro hooks for describing performance characteristics of the target hardware. You could theoretically set up a few key macros to help gcc favor "smaller" instructions while optimizing.

Based on very limited information from [this question](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-01/msg00327.html) and its [one reply](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-01/msg00328.html), you might be able to get some gain from the TARGET_RTX_COSTS costs hook. I haven't yet done enough follow up research to verify this.

I would guess that hooking into the compiler like this will be more useful than any specific C++ idioms.

Please let us know if you manage any performance gain. I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

If a processor has various length (multi-byte) instructions, the best you can do is to write your code to help the compiler make use of the smaller instruction sizes.

### Get The Code Working Robustly & Correct first.

Debugging optimized code is more difficult than debugging code that is not optimized.  The symbols used by the debugger line up with the source code better.  During optimization, the compiler can eliminate code, which gets your code out-of-sync with the source listing.

### Know Your Assembly Instructions

Not all processors have variable length instructions.  Become familiar with your processors instruction set.  Find out which instructions are small (one byte) versus multi-byte.

Write Code to Use Small Assembly Instructions
Help out your compiler and write your code to take advantage of the small length instructions.

Print out the assembly language code to verify that the compiler uses the small instructions.

Change your code if necessary to help out the compiler.

*There is no guarantee that the compiler will use small instructions.  The compiler emits instructions that it thinks will have the best performance according to the optimization settings.*

### Write Your Own Assembly Language Function

After generating the assembly language source code, you are now better equipped to replace the high level language with an assembly language version.  You have the freedom to use small instructions.

### Beware the Jabberwocky

Smaller instructions may not be the best solution in all cases.  For example, the Intel Processors have block instructions (perform operations on blocks of data).  These block instructions perform better than loops of small instructions.  However, the block instructions take up more bytes than the smaller instructions.

The processor will fetch as many bytes as necessary, depending on the instruction, into its instruction cache.  If you can write loops or code that fits into the cache, the instruction sizes become less of a concern.

Also, many processors will use large instructions to communicate with other processors, such as a floating point processor.  Reduction of floating point math in your program may reduce the quanitity of these instructions.

### Trim the Code Tree & Reduce the Branches

In general, branching slows down processing.  Branches are the change of execution to a new location, such as loops and function calls.  Processors love to data instructions, because they don't have to reload the instruction pipeline.  Increasing the amount of data instructions and reducing the quantity of branches will improve performance, usually without regards to the instruction sizes.